# CSS Push menu will ease in but not east out

Tags: html, css

I am creating a push menu. I can get the menu, body, header, main, and footer to push open just as I want it, but when you close the menu, the menu disappears, while everything else eases back the same as it opened. I want the menu to ease back the same way as everything else and not "disappear".

I've looked at the code to long I think and just need another set of eyes.

You can see a demo here: http://designs.totaleeyou.com/jml-development/ Just click the MAIN in the top left corner.

Here is the section of the CSS that handles the transition:

```
body,
body.has-active-menu-push-left,
body.has-active-menu-push-right,
header.scroll,
header ul.logo,
#menu-push-left,
#menu-push-right,
a.menu-close i.fa-times-circle-o,
.page-masking {
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
        -moz-transition:all 0.5s;
            -ms-transition:all 0.5s;
                -o-transition:all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
body.has-active-menu-push-left,
#menu-push-left {
    -webkit-transform:translate(100%, 0);
        -moz-transform:translate(100%, 0);
        -ms-transform:translate(100%, 0);
            -o-transform:translate(100%, 0);
  transform:translate(100%, 0);
}
body.has-active-menu-push-right,
#menu-push-right {
    -webkit-transform:translate(-100%, 0);
        -moz-transform:translate(-100%, 0);
        -ms-transform:translate(-100%, 0);
            -o-transform:translate(-100%, 0);
  transform:translate(-100%, 0);
}
@media only screen and (min-width:780px) {
    body.has-active-menu-push-left,
    #menu-push-left {
        -webkit-transform:translate(500px, 0);
            -moz-transform:translate(500px, 0);
            -ms-transform:translate(500px, 0);
                -o-transform:translate(500px, 0);
      transform:translate(500px, 0);
    }
    body.has-active-menu-push-right,
    #menu-push-right {
        -webkit-transform:translate(-500px, 0);
            -moz-transform:translate(-500px, 0);
            -ms-transform:translate(-500px, 0);
                -o-transform:translate(-500px, 0);
      transform:translate(-500px, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle. The `display`property cannot be animated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `display:none;` in `#menu-push-left, #menu-push-right`.
Eases don't work with `display`

Comment: Thank you Dmitriy. I knew I was missing something. It is always the small things.